# How to manage state in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, state-management

I have a page from which I navigate to another page and do something there , when I press back button, the current page simply pop  and previous page keep as it is. I have to refresh it to make changes. 
I want, when I make change to second page, first page should automatically get updated according to it.

Comment: Post your code of the first page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read a little about managing state in flutter.

There are few very good ideas on how to approach this problem.

You can try with fairly simple [Scoped Model](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/scoped_model).

or little bit more confusing [Inherited widgets](https://ericwindmill.com/using-flutter-inherited-widgets-effectively/). If you ever used `Theme.of(context)` or `Navigator.of(context)` that is basically inherited widget. Just a little more harder to set up properly.

Check this amazing presentation on managing it from google io 2018
https://youtu.be/RS36gBEp8OI